# Flutter Firebase/Admob with multiple environments

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob, environment

I have two firebase project, one for dev and one for my live environment.
The same goes for the android configuration, one "dev" and one "live" environment.

Now im trying to use the flutter Firebase Admob package.
Each environment has a different app id like com.myapp.dev and com.myapp.live

I think on the app mob site only com.myapp.live is available. Do I need as well here two configs or can't I just show test ads without it?
Or how the connection works?

If I copy the Admob app id (probably related to com.myapp.live?) and use it in the android manifest under the main and/or the "dev" env folder I get always an error that Admob is not configured correctly.

Every other firebase service works fine with the google.services split-up in the different env folders.

EDIT:
I created a new Admob entry for com.myapp.dev, linked it with firebase and it still not work when im using the new Admob app id.